# Handle Authentication Prompt in ChromeDriver

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to test our company wide SSO services through Nightwatch. Unfortunately, it uses an Authentication Required prompt, for which Nightwatch does not have a build-in solution

The accepted solution is to send the username and password with the url, as `http://username:pasword@url` . However, our SSO solution requires some prior input, after which a redirect takes place, and the query part of the URL changes.

I have tried determening the URL with a callback function:
`browser.url(function(result) {
      // return the current url
      console.log(result);
    });`
but a status -1 is returned:
`{ status: -1, value: null, errorStatus: '', error: '' }`
I have tried to send keys, but nothing works. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can manipulate the authentication headers using a proxy and declare the proxy as a chromeOption in your desired caps. I am not sure what you mean about prior input to get the prompt can you explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: Before the application gets to the Authentication Prompt, it needs to fill in a value in a textfield.

Basically, the script does this:
```browser.url(url); // Application redirects to a unique hash
browser.setValue(login, "value");
browser.click('submit'); // Application redirects to another unique hash
//Authenication prompt appears```
I cannot change the previous part, it is part of a company wide application.

My desired caps?

Comment: So in your chrome browser capability in your nightwatch.conf.js file you would add the proxy like the code snippet at the end of this comment. If you use a proxy to send a Authentication Header it will be sent in your requests to the page and it doesn't matter at which point you hit the auth it will be skipped automatically. `chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          args: ['--proxy-server=http://localhost:8001'],
        },`